# Accessing a Flexible array Member in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct TestCase TestCase;
typedef struct TestCase {   
    char * userName;
    TestCase *c[];    // flexible array member
} TestCase;
```

And in another File I'm trying to set the flexible array member to NULL, but this doesn't seem to work (I'm not allowed to change how it's been defined)

```
void readIn(FILE * file, TestCase ** t) {
    *t = malloc(sizeof(TestCase));

    (*t)->c = NULL; //gives the error

}
```

I'm using double pointers because that's what's been specified for me (This isn't the entire code, but just a snipit). (As there is also code later to free the variables allocated).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what  error do you get?

Comment: "Invalid use of flexible array member"

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718198/how-to-access-array-of-flexible-arrays-in-cache-friendly-manner

Comment: Note that you will need to know how many entries are allocated to the FAM somehow.  I suppose you could allocate an extra pointer and mark that as null, but you do have to allocate the space for the `c` test case pointers when you allocate the base structure.  It's the only way it can be made to work.

Comment: SO 28718198 is related (and probably worth a read), but it is not a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
 (*t)->c = NULL;
```

This tries to assign `NULL` to an array, which isn't allowed. It would be like writing something like this:

```
int array[137];
array = NULL; // Not allowed
```

When you have a flexible array member, the intent is that when you `malloc` memory for the object, you overallocate the memory you need to make room for the array elements. For example, this code

```
*t = malloc(sizeof(TestCase) + numArrayElems * sizeof(TestCase*));
```

will allocate a new `TestCase` which has an array of `numArrayElems` pointers.

If you don't know in advance how many pointers you'll need, then you probably should switch away from using flexible array members and just use normal pointers.